# Data is not passing to fragment from view pager adapter in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am passing data to a fragment using View-Pager Adapter.
My data is coming until View-Pager Adapter but is not showing in the fragment.

this is my view pager adapter code.

```java
public class ExensesViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
   private MonthsTotal monthsTotal;
    public ExensesViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext, MonthsTotal monthsTotal) {
        super(fm);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.monthsTotal = monthsTotal;
        Logger.e("ExensesViewPagerAdapter");
        Logger.json(new Gson().toJson(monthsTotal));
    }
    /*public ExensesViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }*/
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return AmountFragment.newInstance(monthsTotal);
            case 1:
                return  GraphFragment.newInstance(monthsTotal);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is my fragment code where I am getting the data.

```java
    public static AmountFragment newInstance(MonthsTotal monthsTotal) {
        Logger.e("AmountFragment");
        Logger.json(new Gson().toJson(monthsTotal));
        AmountFragment fragment = new AmountFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("allExpenseData", monthsTotal);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Please help me to solve.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend to display a default fragment...  Because if the position is not 0 or 1 you return null... So can you show us the code where you use the `ExensesViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: @Vall0n      
                monthsTotal = response.body().getData();

                monthlyData = monthsTotal.getMonthlyData();

                user_joining_date = monthsTotal.getUser_joining_date();
                joiningYear = TimeUtils.convertToReadableYear(user_joining_date);
                Hawk.put("joiningYear", joiningYear);

                frag_pager.setAdapter(new ExensesViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), context, monthsTotal));

Comment: Can you post your complete `ExensesViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: ` @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }`  last few line code .. remains i posted in q.

Comment: Any warnings or errors in logical when running the app?

Comment: No , i am getting data till ExensesViewPagerAdapter . if i am printing log .but in fragment not getting updated data

Comment: K, can you post more code form the `AmountFragment`? How do you retrieve and use the `monthsTotal` data?

Comment: monthsTotal = getArguments().getParcelable("allExpenseData");
   for (int i = 0; i < monthsTotal.getMonthlyData().size(); i++) {
   // my logical code 
    }

Comment: K, please post more code.. Maybe also the part where you use the `ExensesViewPagerAdapter`. Till know everything looks good

Comment: in for loop am displaying data on views, that's it.

Comment: Please replace `getFragmentManager()` in `new ExensesViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), context, monthsTotal)` with `getChildFragmentManager()`